# What are the pitfalls of hosting ISPConfig with docker?

Tags: docker, web-hosting

Currently I use a VPS with ISPConfig to manage some websites.
I would like to create a docker image with ISPConfig.
Because I believe it would be pain free to move to another host.
So except from some more IO on the system, what should I except as a disadvantage from doing such a thing?

PS: I'm a docker newbie.